# How to get last indexed record in Solr

Tags: solr

In my Solr core, I have **ID** field which is a primary key. I defined it like this:

```
<field name="ID" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
```

I'm indexing my records using command prompt. After that I want to querying to get last ID. My query like this:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/StorageCore/select?fl=ID&q=*%3A*&sort=ID%20desc
```

It gives me this result:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "fl":"ID",
      "sort":"ID desc"}},
  "response":{"numFound":909,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "ID":"99"},
      {
        "ID":"98"},
      {
        "ID":"97"},
      {
        "ID":"96"},
      {
        "ID":"95"},
      {
        "ID":"94"},
      {
        "ID":"93"},
      {
        "ID":"92"},
      {
        "ID":"911"},
      {
        "ID":"910"}]
  }
```

So the result is not what I want. I want to get **911** not **99**. How can I solve this problem?

### Update

After @MatsLindh and @ Abhijit Bashetti assistance, I created a new field which type is **int** after that I copied all my uniqueKey field that is **ID** to the new field. So it worked. My query response like this now:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":2,
    "params":{
      "q":"idCopy:*",
      "fl":"idCopy",
      "sort":"idCopy desc",
      "rows":"9999"}},
  "response":{"numFound":909,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "idCopy":[911]},
      {
        "idCopy":[910]},
      {
        "idCopy":[909]},
      {
        "idCopy":[908]},
      {
        "idCopy":[907]},
      {
        "idCopy":[906]},
      {
        "idCopy":[905]},
      {
        "idCopy":[904]},
      {
        "idCopy":[903]},
      {
        "idCopy":[902]},
      {
        "idCopy":[901]},
      {
        "idCopy":[900]},
```

Comment: I think its because your field is of type string and not of type integer...If you change it to Integer it should work

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti I tried to do it as **pint** but it gives me this **uniquekey can not be pint**

Comment: try with int as type

Comment: If you're just after the document that has changed most recently, you can probably use the `_version_` field for ordering instead (since it has docValues, but is usually non-indexed). Otherwise, create a second field with the `pint` type, and use a `copyField` instruction to copy content into that field instead. That way you won't have to change the existing field type for id, and can let it be a string in the future as well.

Comment: I agree with MatsLindh...You can do the above approach as well. But if you are sure that the field ID will have numeric values...I would suggest to have the int type for the same instead of having 2 fields

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti @MatsLindh thanks both of you. I created new field as a `int` and I copied all `ID` field to new field. So it's working correctly now.

Comment: You probably want to make sure that the new field is `multiValued="false"` (so you avoid the array when it's being returned), just to be clear that there is no support for multiple values in that field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `fieldType` of your field `ID` from `string` to `int`.

It should be like below.

```
<field name="IDS"  type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" docValues="true"/>
```

When you have the `fieldType` as `string` the result is like below.

[image: Image with string type]

When you have the `fieldType` as `int` the result is like below.

[image]

Comment: I changed it to **int** but I'm getting this error. **StorageCore: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core StorageCore: Can't load schema C:\solr-7.7.0\server\solr\StorageCore\conf\schema.xml: Unknown fieldType 'int' specified on field ID
Please check your logs for more information**

Comment: check if your schema files has entry like <fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" docValues="true" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>